# No SCM URL was provided to perform the release from during maven release

Tags: java, git, maven, bitbucket, devops

I am getting below error while performing mvn release:perform

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.1:perform (default-cli) on project smartpra-common: No SCM URL was provided to perform the release from -> [Help 1]

I am  trying to connect bit bucket  using scm tag.
Below is URL for cloning  my project from bitbucket
http://wusazedev12:7990/scm/smartpra/smartpra-common.git

so configured scm as shown below.

```
<scm>
    <connection>scm:git:http://wusazedev12:7990/scm/smartpra/smartpra-common.git</connection>
    <url>http://wusazedev12:7990/scm/smartpra/smartpra-common.git</url>
    <developerConnection>scm:git:http://wusazedev12:7990/scm/smartpra/smartpra-common.git</developerConnection>
    <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>
```

I am new to this so not sure whether i configure correctly.